# exception when trying to fetch more than 1 thousand customer(s) and invoice(s) from QBO API

Tags: c#, asp.net, quickbooks-online

I have more than 1000 customer(s) and invoice(s) and I am trying to fetch all those customers and invoice(s) into a drop-down list.

Documentation on the QBO site suggests that we should need to use pagination if I want to load all the customers in a grid, but what I want is to load all the customer(s) and invoice(s) in a drop-down list.

I am getting the following exception when I try to fetch more than 1000 customer(s) and invoice(s):

> Validation Exception was thrown.
>
> Details: QueryValidationError: value 100000 is too large. Max allowed value is 1000.

I am trying to fetch all the customers  using the following code

```
public static List<Customer> GetAllQBOCustomers(ServiceContext context)
{
   return Helper.FindAll<Customer>(context, new Customer(),1,100000);
}
```

Comment: So, your question title says "a million", your code says "100 thousand", and the exception says "you can't retrieve more than 1000". I'm seeing a slight "attention to detail" problem here..

Comment: I am using Kendo Grid to load all the customers and invoices and I disabled server operation = false for kendo grid, that's why I don't want to send any request to the server. I just want to load all the customers and invoices at once. for clarity, I mentioned above that I want to load all the records in a dropdown list

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the below code and solved my issue.

```
1. First I get the count of all the customers 
2. Then I get all the customers in chunks and the chunk size is 1000 
3. Create a List for customers. 
4. Define 3 integer type variables for counting. 
5. After that use do-while loop  
6. Add all the customers are added to the main customer list


        string strQuery = "Select Count(*) From Customer";
        string custCount = qboAccess.GetCutomerCount(qboInz.QboServiceContext, strQuery);
        List<qboData.Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        int maxSize = 0;
        int position = 1;
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(custCount);
        do
        {
          var custList = qboAccess.GetAllQBOEntityRecords(qboInz.QboServiceContext, new Customer(), position, 1000);
          customers.AddRange(custList);
          maxSize += custList.Count();
          position += 1000;
        } while (count > maxSize);
```

Comment: This will work but I imagine it might be quite slow

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward answer is to loop enough times to get the records you need:

```
public static List<Customer> GetAllQBOCustomers(ServiceContext context)
{
    var list = new List<Customer>();
    for (int i=0; i<=10000; i+= 1000)
    {
        var results = Helper.FindAll<Customer>(context, new Customer(),i, 1000);
        list.AddRange(results);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Or if you want to try to do it in parallel (and the API allows concurrent connections):

```
public static List<Customer> GetAllQBOCustomers(ServiceContext context)
{
    var bag = new ConcurrentBag<Customer>();
    Parallel.ForEach( Enumerable.Range(0, 10), i =>
    {
        var results = Helper.FindAll<Customer>(context, new Customer(),i * 1000, 1000);
        bag.AddRange(results);
    });
    return bag.ToList();
}
```

Since the series of calls is likely to be expensive, I suggest you cache the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download those records all at once. That is what the error is telling you - very clearly. There's no magic way to avoid the server's rules.

However, I really think you should not download them all at once anyway. A drop-down list is not a good way to display that amount of data to users. Consider the user experience - would you want to scroll through a list of thousands of customers to try and find the one you want? Or would it be easier to start typing part of the name and have it pop up a short list of possible matches to choose from?

A more user-friendly way to implement this would be use an auto-complete box instead of a drop-down list, and after the user has typed a few characters, it can use AJAX to search the API for customers whose names or IDs contain those characters. Then you'll only need to return a small number of records each time, and the user will not be stuck having to scroll for 10 minutes just to find a customer at the bottom of a list of 10,000 records.

Comment: Dear, I know all the things which you suggest above, but some time client requirements are very strange, and they want what exactly they suggest,
so we can't suggest any better solution to them, that's why I post that question, I solved the above case and posted my answer here as well.

thanks for your quick response and nice advise

Comment: I know all about customers...but also sometimes our job as technical people is to politely tell them that we have thought of a better idea. As soon as you explain that it makes the application easier to use, or makes it cheaper, or quicker, or whatever the advantage might be, in my experience they are usually happy to agree to the change. In this case, if you can't convince them beforehand, then I think they might realise the problem when they actually start to try and use the ridiculous drop-down list :-). Good luck with your project.